# find by $type number in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've got following documents

```
> db.people.insert({name: "Bob"})
> db.people.insert({name: 42})
```

If I need find by type `String` I can use:

```
> db.people.find({name: { $type: 2 })
```

Where [2 is Type Number of String](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type)

But how could I find by type `Number`?

```
> typeof db.people.findOne({name: 42}).name
number
```

There is no type `number` in [possible types](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type).

**upd**: I've tried to find by 16 and 18 types. It's not works.

```
> db.people.find({ name: 42 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("509645ae5013826ee61d96ac"), "name" : 42 }
> db.people.find({name: { $type: 16 }})
> db.people.find({name: { $type: 18 }})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is only [one numeric type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Number) in JavaScript (`Number`), which is represented in binary as an IEEE 754 floating point number (double).

In the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) this will be represented as a double (type 1), so you should be able to find with:

```
db.people.find({name: { $type: 1 }})
```

There are some `mongo` shell helpers if you want to insert different BSON [data types](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions):

```
42              // Type 1:  double (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point, 8 bytes)
NumberInt(42)   // Type 16: int32  (32-bit signed integer, 4 bytes)
NumberLong(42)  // Type 18: int64  (64-bit signed integer, 8 bytes)
```

So for example:

```
db.people.insert({ name: 'default', num: 42 })
db.people.insert({ name: 'NumberLong', num: NumberLong(42) })
db.people.insert({ name: 'NumberInt', num: NumberInt(42) })
```

The different numeric representations will still match if you do a `find()` on a number that can be represented in multiple formats (i.e. a 32-bit integer can also be represented as a double or int64).

For example:

```
db.people.find({num:42})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50965aa3038d8c8e85fd3f45"),
    "name" : "default",
    "num" : 42
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50965aa3038d8c8e85fd3f46"),
    "name" : "NumberLong",
    "num" : NumberLong(42)
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50965aa3038d8c8e85fd3f47"),
    "name" : "NumberInt",
    "num" : 42
}
```

However if you find by `$type`, the BSON representation is different:

```
> db.people.find({num: { $type: 1 }})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50965aa3038d8c8e85fd3f45"),
    "name" : "default",
    "num" : 42
}

> db.people.find({num: { $type: 16 }})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50965aa3038d8c8e85fd3f47"),
    "name" : "NumberInt",
    "num" : 42
}

> db.people.find({num: { $type: 18 }})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50965aa3038d8c8e85fd3f46"),
    "name" : "NumberLong",
    "num" : NumberLong(42)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript , there is no real difference between int32 and int64. Mongodb shell however  uses 32 bits, unless said otherwise (using the Number(..) constructor).

You should try to query like this :

```
db.people.find({name: { $type: 16 })
```

where 16 is the type code for integer : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

```
db.people.find({
    $or: [
        {name: {$type: 1}},       // double
        {name: {$type: 16}},      // int
        {name: {$type: 18}},      // long
        {name: {$type: 19}},      // decimal
    ]
})
```

Check the document here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#std-label-document-type-available-types