# Find a post where author is Numberlong

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to query a post where the author is numberlong format (Integer 64 bits) 
but I don't know how to do it with PHP driver 
It works with small integers (32 bits) here is the range array I'm using :

```
$rangeQuery=array('author'=>intval($tmp->info['user']));
$fields=array('title' => true, 'type' => true,'subtype' => true, 'active' => true);
$rows = $markers->find($rangeQuery,$fields);
```

But it doesn't return the author where the author is a  64 bits integer

Comment: For numeric types there shouldn't be any difference in querying an int32 versus int64 (both should match, unless you specifically want to match by BSON type). See also: [find by $type number in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217908/find-by-type-number-in-mongodb). The PHP `intval()` function only handles 64-bit values if both your hardware and your PHP are 64-bit. What's the output of `php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'`?

Comment: It's the 64 bit value. I really don't know where is the problem ..

Comment: Can you include an example of a 64-bit `author` id as queried from the `mongo` shell (that you can't find from PHP)? Is this possibly stored as a string rather than a NumberLong()?

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("52be999b211b6fe37a8b456b"),  "author" : "NumberLong(100000055563854)", "duration" : NumberLong(15), "description" : "dgeae", "title" : "dfg", "date" : ISODate("2013-12-28T09:27:55Z"), "contact" : "fghghfgh", "active" : NumberLong(1) }

Comment: What version of the MongoDB PHP driver are you using? I haven't been able to reproduce the problem yet.

Answer (score -1):

The sql option is CHAR_LENGTH() as i've read some istant ago...
This is the link to the original source.

[MySQL - How to select data by string length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870937/mysql-how-to-select-data-by-string-length)

Comment: This is not SQL question! it's totally different!